# Extract IPv4 and IPv6 Address Ranges in Bash?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script in which I need to extract IPv4 and IPv6 Address Ranges from multiple strings and then format it as per the requirements before saving to the file.

I've got the regex working fine: http://regexr.com?38jsb (Not optimized, roughly added)

However, with bash it throws an error if i use with `egrep` which states `egrep: repetition-operator operand invalid`

Here's my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

regex="(?>(?>([a-f\d]{1,4})(?>:(?1)){3}|(?!(?:.*[a-f\d](?>:|$)){})((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,6})?::(?2)?)|(?>(?>(?1)(?>:(?1)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f\d]:){6,})(?3)?::(?>((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,4}):)?)?(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)(?>\.(?4)){3}))\/\d{1,2}"

echo "v=abc ip4:127.0.0.1/19 ip4:192.168.1.1/32 ip4:192.168.2.50/20 ip6:2001:4860:4000::/36 ip6:2404:6800:4000::/36 ip6:2607:f8b0:4000::/36 ip6:2800:3f0:4000::/36 ip6:2a00:1450:4000::/36 ip6:2c0f:fb50:4000::/36 ~all" | egrep -o $regex
```

How can i extract both type of IP ranges in bash? What's a better solution?

**Note:** I'm using sample data for testing purpose

Comment: Untested, but fairly certain `egrep` won't work with a number of operators/classes you're using (e.g. `\d`). Try switching to perl style regex with `grep -Po`. Also you should quote `"$regex"`.

Comment: Nope, That didn't work! Any other suggestions? Thanks for posting btw!

Comment: Are you using GNU grep?

Comment: I was testing it on Mac OS X. And as per the comments in below solutions, It seems like `-P` doesn't work on OS X, Which is why i couldn't get it working. But i got a better solution from @mklement0 for this. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, *single-quote* the regex variable assignment (`regex='...'`).

Then, use `grep -Po` (and double-quote `$regex`), as @BroSlow suggests (note that `-P` is not available on all platforms (e.g., OSX)) -- `-P` activates support for PCREs (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions), which is required for your regex.

To put it all together:

```
regex='(?>(?>([a-f\d]{1,4})(?>:(?1)){3}|(?!(?:.*[a-f\d](?>:|$)){})((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,6})?::(?2)?)|(?>(?>(?1)(?>:(?1)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f\d]:){6,})(?3)?::(?>((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,4}):)?)?(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)(?>\.(?4)){3}))\/\d{1,2}'
txt="v=abc ip4:127.0.0.1/19 ip4:192.168.1.1/32 ip4:192.168.2.50/20 ip6:2001:4860:4000::/36 ip6:2404:6800:4000::/36 ip6:2607:f8b0:4000::/36 ip6:2800:3f0:4000::/36 ip6:2a00:1450:4000::/36 ip6:2c0f:fb50:4000::/36 ~all"
echo "$txt" | grep -Po "$regex"
```

---

**Alternative**: Following @l'L'l's example, here's a greatly simplified solution that works with the sample data (again relies on `-P`):

```
echo "$txt" | grep -Po '\bip[46]:\K[^ ]+'
```

Variant for **OSX**, where `grep` doesn't support `-P`:

```
echo "$txt" | egrep -o '\<ip[46]:[^ ]+' | cut -c 5-
```

Comment: Now if only OS X grep had the `-Po` option these type of things would be much easier :)

Comment: @l'L'l: Agreed; I've added an OSX variant of the simplified solution.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the solution, the simplified solution is much better than what i had. Perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

This pattern should work in combination with sed:

```
str="v=abc ip4:127.0.0.1/19 ip4:192.168.1.1/32 ip4:192.168.2.50/20 ip6:2001:4860:4000::/36 ip6:2404:6800:4000::/36 ip6:2607:f8b0:4000::/36 ip6:2800:3f0:4000::/36 ip6:2a00:1450:4000::/36 ip6:2c0f:fb50:4000::/36 ~all"

echo $str | grep -s -i -o "ip[0-9]\:[a-z0-9\.:/]*" --color=always | sed 's/ip[0-9]\://g'
```

output:

```
127.0.0.1/19
192.168.1.1/32
192.168.2.50/20
2001:4860:4000::/36
2404:6800:4000::/36
2607:f8b0:4000::/36
2800:3f0:4000::/36
2a00:1450:4000::/36
2c0f:fb50:4000::/36
```

omit the `--color=always` to exclude color output if desired.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I had to go with @mklement0 solution as it's more simpler. P.S Upvoted though.